# Can anyone guide me on how to learn stackexchange language?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, markdown

My exams are nearing and I have been posting question on vector calculus which are not answered yet because I'm writing in simple English. Many people have edited my questions. Kindly guide me on how to learn that...

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to learn how to write math formulas? [This is a good start](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Unrelated: please slowdown on the texting language ("thanks you r right . can u guide me on how u did that ?" for example is probably making some users here nervous).

Answer (score 2):

look up Latex, if what your looking for is how to show your equations like,
$\frac{a^b}{c^d}$ rather than (a^b)/(c^d), by adding $ signs before and after a equation you can use latex directly with the forum. If that is what your asking?

the MathJax Link above paw gave is a must read

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by *stackexchange language*.

If you mean [Markdown](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/markdown/info), which is used for formatting (i.e., things like **bold**, *italics*, links, lists, etc.) have a look at [Markdown help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

If you mean [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info), which is used to write mathematics on this site, you can have a look, for example, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).