# A suggestion to add to review queues ( First questions - Share feedback)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I suggest that you add this type of examples to review queues ( First questions - Share feedback) it will be much of help for the new users and the one who reviews the question, I know there is a Custom comments option but this will be much easier.

**Examples of what I suggest you add**:

> Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

> Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: My point is the examples I provided are used most of the time, so it being an option to feedback is a good idea since the question that users don't use mathjax for example, but the question is obvious and clear but the only thing missing is using mathjax , the one who reviewed the question will choose to put "clarify your specific problem or provide additional details " which he did, or "edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer." and the question is understandable, so he chooses one the two and that really didn't help the new user.

Comment: I missed your second link, (How to ask a good question) that you included in the first example, previously.  So I think it is very comprehensive and informative, and I'd like that option featured in the "Share Feedback" option, too!

Comment: @amWhy will if it to be added, it's up to the mod to phrase the sentences and added or remove whatever they agree on but stay at the same concept and, FYI the link (How to ask a good question) is there I don't what you mean by *I missed it*