# The links on the "How can I format mathematics here" page are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, hyperlinks, help-center

On the page https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation, there are two links:

https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

When I click on either of these links in Firefox, I get a message "Secure connection failed" with the error code SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP.

The links work fine if I change "meta.math" to "math.meta":

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

[Do we have an equation editing HOWTO?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Note that the title of the first link has apparently changed since the link was placed on the help page, so it redirects to

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

(I have not figured out how to coerce SE into showing the actual URLs instead of the names of the linked pages, but hovering over the link works.)

Comment: See related question on meta.se: [meta.*.stackexchange.com redirection does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393351/meta-stackexchange-com-redirection-does-not-work)

Comment: For the time being please use the links starting with math.meta instead of meta.math

Comment: Also be aware that if you habitually point new users to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and advise them to follow the links there, as I do, you should instead provide the links explicitly until they are corrected on the help page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now updated the links on [this Help Center page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to use the current URLs for the linked posts.

(This site-specific Help Center page is actually set as moderator-editable, so the site mods should be able to fix issues with it directly.)