# reference for tex on site

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where is the latex reference please](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please)

Hi, I having just started learning how to type in Tex and I have been discouraged from typing notational heavy mathematics. I wonder if the mods could provide a reference for Tex on the site that is easily accessible when needed?

Comment: Please see this previous question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please

Comment: Also see: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto which is currently 'featured' (so it appears to the right of every page on the main site) and in the FAQ.